# JpGraph legend order

Tags: php, diagram, legend, jpgraph

I'm using an accumulated bar plot with JpGraph and want to change the order in which the items appear in the legend (I want to sort them alphanumerically). I've checked the documentation, but didn't find anything related: do I have any options for achieving this? (JpGraph seems to sort the legend on its own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I dont believe there is directly, however:

> By default the ordering of the texts in te legend will be the same as
>   the order the plots are added to the graph. It is also possible to
>   reverse this order in the legend with a call to the method
>   Legend::Reverse()

```
$graph->legend->SetReverse();
```

You could programatically sort your series as you wish before pushing them to the graph in your desired order to achieve what you're after...